# how to update the object in child component when object property in changes in the parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 2 components

Parent component is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: `
    <child [obj]="obj"> </child>
  `,
  styleUrls: [''],
})
export class parentComponent implements OnInit{

 obj = {
  id:1;
  name:'abc'
 }

}
```

and child component is

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  templateUrl: '',
  styleUrls: [''],
})
export class ChildComponetimplements OnInit{

   @Input() obj : any;

}
```

If I change any of the property in the obj in the parent, it is not getting updated in the child component.

Maybe because the obj reference is not changed.

Please suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: In parent component, do you really use `templateUrl`? For inline DOM you need to use `template` instead

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `ngOnChanges` like below

**Parent Component**

```
export class AppComponent  {

  obj = {
    id:1,
    name:'abc'
  }

  name = 'Angular';

  changeObject() {
    this.obj.id++;
  }
}
```

**Parent Template**

```
<button (click)="changeObject()">Change Object</button>

<hello name="{{ name }}" [obj]="obj"></hello>
```

**Child Component**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'hello',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1><p>{{ obj | json }}</p>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`]
})
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges { 
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() obj;

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    this.obj = changes.currentValue ? changes.currentValue.obj : this.obj;
  }
}
```

Working example is here in [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4uym75)

Answer (score 0):

**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-update-the-object-in-child-component-when-object-propert?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

```
  obj = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Hello'
  }

  changeObject() {
    this.obj.name = 'Hello change';
  }
```

Comment: Your answer would probably be helpful with some comentary.

Comment: Thanks @dwjohnston

Answer (score 0):

Use `ngOnChanges` to listen to changes of input properties. You will pass the object from parent to child and whenever there is any change in the object that you have passed as input to the child will give `SimpleChanges` object in `ngOnChanges` hook of child component.

```
interface OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void
}
```

**Example**

```
@Component({selector: 'my-cmp', template: `...`})
class MyComponent implements OnChanges {
  // TODO(issue/24571): remove '!'.
  @Input()
  prop !: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.prop contains the old and the new value...
  }
}
```

For more on [ngOnChanges](https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges)